# Double brackets {{ }}

Tags: brackets

How to type the double bracket '{{b, a}}' in tex just as the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need negative spaces `\!` to get the braces close to each other. There may be a better way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\( \{\!\!\{a,b\}\!\!\} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\doubleBrackets[1]{$\{\!\{ #1 \}\!\}$}

\begin{document}

These are double \{ \} brackets \doubleBrackets{b, a}.

\end{document}
```